# Is there any way to do batch via vSphere API?

Tags: c#, vmware

I'm using vSphere API to retrieve all VMs in vCenter. However, I didn't find any official document or code example mentioning requests with batching/paging. My code is like below:

```
        VimClient client = new VimClient();
        client.Connect(host, CommunicationProtocol.Https, 443);
        client.Login(userName, password);
        IList<EntityViewBase> vms = client.FindEntityViews(typeof(VirtualMachine), null, null, null);
```

I checked the source code decompiled by ReSharper. Interestingly, there is a nullable parameter "beginEntity"; but there is no way to specify the number of entities to retrieve. Is there completely no hope that they may support batch?

```
public List<EntityViewBase> FindEntityViews(Type viewType, ManagedObjectReference beginEntity, NameValueCollection filter, string[] properties)
{
  IList<ViewBase> viewBaseList = (IList<ViewBase>) null;
  ManagedObjectReference beginEntity1 = beginEntity ?? this._serviceContent.RootFolder;
  string[] strArray = (string[]) null;
  if (filter != null && filter.Count > 0)
  {
    string[] propertyList = new string[filter.Count];
    filter.AllKeys.CopyTo((Array) propertyList, 0);
    strArray = VimClient.ValidatePropertyPathList(viewType, propertyList);
  }
  ObjectContent[] objectContentArray = new PropertyCollector(this, this._serviceContent.PropertyCollector).RetrieveProperties(new PropertyFilterSpec[1]
  {
    EntityViewBase.GetSearchFilterSpec(this, beginEntity1, new PropertySpec()
    {
      All = new bool?(false),
      Type = viewType.Name,
      PathSet = strArray
    })
  });
  List<ManagedObjectReference> managedObjectReferenceList = new List<ManagedObjectReference>();
  if (objectContentArray != null)
  {
    foreach (ObjectContent objectContent in objectContentArray)
    {
      if (beginEntity == null || !objectContent.Obj.Value.Equals(beginEntity.Value) || !objectContent.Obj.Type.Equals(beginEntity.Type))
      {
        if (filter != null && filter.Count > 0)
        {
          DynamicProperty[] propSet = objectContent.PropSet;
          if (propSet != null)
          {
            Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DynamicProperty dynamicProperty in propSet)
              dictionary.Add(dynamicProperty.Name, dynamicProperty.Val);
            if (dictionary.Count > 0 && VimClient.MatchProperyList(filter, viewType, (IDictionary<string, object>) dictionary))
              managedObjectReferenceList.Add(objectContent.Obj);
          }
        }
        else
          managedObjectReferenceList.Add(objectContent.Obj);
      }
    }
  }
  if (managedObjectReferenceList.Count > 0)
    viewBaseList = (IList<ViewBase>) this.GetViewsByMorefs((IEnumerable<ManagedObjectReference>) managedObjectReferenceList, properties);
  List<EntityViewBase> entityViewBaseList = (List<EntityViewBase>) null;
  if (viewBaseList != null)
  {
    entityViewBaseList = new List<EntityViewBase>();
    foreach (ViewBase viewBase in (IEnumerable<ViewBase>) viewBaseList)
    {
      EntityViewBase entityViewBase = viewBase as EntityViewBase;
      entityViewBaseList.Add(entityViewBase);
    }
  }
  return entityViewBaseList;
}


public List<ViewBase> GetViewsByMorefs(IEnumerable<ManagedObjectReference> moRefs, params string[] properties)
{
  Dictionary<string, PropertyFilterSpec> propertyFilterSpecList = new Dictionary<string, PropertyFilterSpec>();
  foreach (ManagedObjectReference moRef in moRefs)
  {
    if (propertyFilterSpecList.ContainsKey(moRef.Type.ToLower()))
    {
      PropertyFilterSpec propertyFilterSpec = propertyFilterSpecList[moRef.Type.ToLower()];
      propertyFilterSpec.ObjectSet = new List<ObjectSpec>((IEnumerable<ObjectSpec>) propertyFilterSpec.ObjectSet)
      {
        new ObjectSpec() { Obj = moRef }
      }.ToArray();
    }
    else
    {
      PropertyFilterSpec resultPropertyFilterSpec;
      Dictionary<string, List<string>> currentAllowedPropertyPath;
      DynamicPropertyFilterSpecGenerator.Generate(moRef, properties, out resultPropertyFilterSpec, out currentAllowedPropertyPath);
      propertyFilterSpecList.Add(moRef.Type.ToLower(), resultPropertyFilterSpec);
    }
  }
  PropertyFilterSpec[] propertyFilterSpecArray = new PropertyFilterSpec[propertyFilterSpecList.Values.Count];
  propertyFilterSpecList.Values.CopyTo(propertyFilterSpecArray, 0);
  ObjectContent[] objectContent = new PropertyCollector(this, this._serviceContent.PropertyCollector).RetrieveProperties(propertyFilterSpecArray);
  List<ViewBase> viewsByMorefs = this.GetViewsByMorefs(moRefs, objectContent, propertyFilterSpecList);
  return viewsByMorefs;
}

private List<ViewBase> GetViewsByMorefs(IEnumerable<ManagedObjectReference> moRefs, ObjectContent[] objectContent, Dictionary<string, PropertyFilterSpec> propertyFilterSpecList)
{
  List<ViewBase> viewBaseList = new List<ViewBase>();
  List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
  foreach (ManagedObjectReference moRef in moRefs)
    stringList.Add(moRef.Value);
  Dictionary<string, ObjectContent> objectContentList = new Dictionary<string, ObjectContent>();
  foreach (ObjectContent objectContent1 in objectContent)
    objectContentList.Add(objectContent1.Obj.Value, objectContent1);
  Dictionary<string, ViewBase> generatedManagedObjectList = new Dictionary<string, ViewBase>();
  foreach (ObjectContent objectContent1 in objectContent)
  {
    if (stringList.Contains(objectContent1.Obj.Value))
    {
      ConstructorInfo constructor = ViewBase.GetViewType(objectContent1.Obj.Type).GetConstructor(new Type[2]
      {
        typeof (VimClient),
        typeof (ManagedObjectReference)
      });
      if (constructor != null)
      {
        ViewBase currentObject = (ViewBase) constructor.Invoke(new object[2]
        {
          (object) this,
          (object) objectContent1.Obj
        });
        ViewBase.SetViewData(currentObject, (string) null, (Dictionary<string, List<string>>) null, objectContentList, generatedManagedObjectList);
        viewBaseList.Add(currentObject);
      }
    }
  }
  return viewBaseList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a dIrect way to achieve this.

However, the second code snippet you posted (the decompiled `FindEntityViews`) shows use of the VMware [`Property Collector`](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-65/index.jsp#com.vmware.wssdk.pg.doc/PG_PropertyCollector.7.1.html)'s method `retrieveProperties`. If you use [`retrievePropertiesEx`](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-65/index.jsp#com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.html?path=4_2_0_2_5_19_41#retrievePropertiesEx) then you can provide it with a max count and then call [`continueRetrievePropertiesEx`](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-65/topic/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.html#continueRetrievePropertiesEx).

Note, though, that in my experience the vSphere API is quite robust, so unless you have many thousands of VMs, you may find that you don't need paging (unless you have other considerations, of course).

Comment: `RetrievePropertiesEx` and `ContinueRetrievePropertiesEx` work well for me! However, I need to implement my own `FindEntityViews` method, which uses a lot of non-public methods (like `VimClient.ValidatePropertyPathList`). Any recommendation for this?

Comment: @LaiwenYi Can you please post your code for RetrievePropertiesEx and ContinueRetrievePropertiesEx which was worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snipped how I achieved batching in the end.

```
VimClient vimClient = new VimClient();
vimClient.Connect(host, CommunicationProtocol.Https, 443);
vimClient.Login(userName, password);

string token = string.Empty;

while (true)
{
    // Construct the property collector
    PropertyCollector propertyCollector = new PropertyCollector(vimClient, vimClient.ServiceContent.PropertyCollector);

    // Retrieve a batch of objects
    RetrieveResult result;
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
         result = propertyCollector.ContinueRetrievePropertiesEx(token);
    else
    {
        result = propertyCollector.RetrievePropertiesEx(new[]
        {
            EntityViewBase.GetSearchFilterSpec(vimClient, vimClient.ServiceContent.RootFolder, new PropertySpec
            {
                All = false,
                Type = typeof(VirtualMachine),
                PathSet = null
            })
        }, new RetrieveOptions { MaxObjects = 100 });
    }

    // Exit early if no entities retrieved
    if (null == result || 0 == result.Objects.Length)
        break;

    // Get the MoRefs of retrieval result
    List<ManagedObjectReference> objectMoRefList = result.Objects.Select(o => o.Obj).ToList();

    // Retrieve the properties of objects
    List <EntityViewBase> entityList = vimClient.GetViewsByMorefs(objectMoRefList)?.Select(viewBase => viewBase as EntityViewBase).ToList();

    // Return the objects and batch retrieval token
    token = new BatchRetrievalToken(result.Token)
    entityList.ForEach(e => yield return e);
}
```